# Java precision issues when getting float from Oracle database - doesn't round correctly

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, precision, bigdecimal

I'm running a JSP web app that retrieves a numerical value from an Oracle database and displays it on a webpage. I manually entered the value of 2929.2, and querying the database by hand confirms that it's stored as that value. When I retrieve it through JSP, though, it shows up as 2929.199951172. How can I fix that? I'm using ResultSets and the getDouble() method. It's stored in Oracle as a float, but - and pardon my noobishness - from my understanding that has as much precision as a Java double and getFloat() is not what I'm looking for.

I've skimmed a few articles about BigDecimal, but I'm hesitant to change everything unless I know it's what I need.

Comment: Well, you need `BigDecimal` because that's its purpose: handling fields in database with exact precision for floating point values.

Comment: Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), and maybe read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (and if you can't follow that, at least read about [ieee-754 rounding rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Rounding_rules)).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: so can I use getBigDecimal() but then cast it to a double, or would I run into the same problems? I can't change the final way the doubles are stored without overhauling the program I'm working on, and at this point my supervisor would probably rather tell our (internal) client to deal with it than do that.

Comment: @slothario once working with `BigDecimal`, keep all the operations using `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `BigDecimal` because that's its purpose: handling floating point values with arbitrary precision. From [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) javadoc:

> Immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers. A `BigDecimal` consists of an arbitrary precision integer unscaled value and a 32-bit integer scale.

This type is heavily used when retrieving data from `DECIMAL` (or `NUMERIC`) fields from database because allows maintaining the precision of the value stored in database. This is specially used in financial applications/operationss.

By the way, you should also change the type used in your Oracle database from `FLOAT` to [`DECIMAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj15260.html) as well.

> I'm hesitant to change everything unless I know it's what I need

If you want/need to handle these numeric values in the right way, you should change *everything* to `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately this is a large corporate data store and I'm not going to be able to change it to decimal. In addition, I'm having to work around a lot of poor design decisions introduced by a large open source program I'm extending (JTrac, specifically). We're using it for way more than it was designed for, and it stores everything as doubles - changing that would be an overhaul that would affect much more than just my little corner of it. I'm not trying to be difficult and I appreciate the feedback, but are there any other fixes?

Comment: @slothario nope, you're out of luck.